# How can I get child id of hatched turtle inside the ask turtle context?

Tags: design-patterns, netlogo

I just started using netlogo and I'm trying to transition away from OOP, so I apologize if my coding paradigm is the source of my issue.

## Problem

Inside an `ask turtle` procedure I have hatched a turtle. I want to create a link to the hatched turtle with the turtle that hatched it. I do not need to remember family ties.

## Attempts to solve the problem

```
ask turtles [
    setxy ( mean [pxcor] of my-territory ) ( mean [pycor] of my-territory )
    show my-territory
    let parent-node [hatch 1]
    [ set color red
      if parent-node != nobody
      [ create-link-with parent-node [ set color green ]
        move-to old-node ;; position the new node near its partner
        fd 8
      ]]]
```

But the hatch gives me the error the it expects a literal value. `1` is a literal, correct? What would be the best way of thinking about how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want

```
if parent-node != nobody [
  ask parent-node [
    hatch 1 [create-link-with myself init-child]
  ]
]
```

where `init-child` holds your initializations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really clear what you're trying to do. What is parent-node? Is that the node doing the hatching? If so, you don't need it at all since the `ask turtles` throws you into the turtle context (ie the turtle doing the commands is the parent-node). And what is old-node? `hatch` will place the new turtle in the same location as the turtle hatching anyway.

If all you are trying to do is have a turtle hatch another, link the hatcher with the hatchee, and then have the child move forward, try this:

```
ask turtles
[ setxy ( mean [pxcor] of my-territory ) ( mean [pycor] of my-territory )      
  hatch 1
  [ set color red
    create-link-with myself [ set color green ]
    forward 8
  ]
]
```

Note that `myself` refers to whatever is doing the asking.